# runtime error with springboot/jpa/mysql => com.sun.proxy.$Proxy68.saveAndFlush(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I am writing my first springboot/jpa/mysql backend using STS.

I am following tutorial from :

https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLdJYl6XU45uLIHaPBQEj-cEMynAl0oeiz

Code is:
Book.java

```
package com.lms.models;

import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity(name = "lms_tbl")
public class Book {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "book_name")
    private String bookName;

    private String author;

    @Column(name = "purchase_date")
    private Date purchaseDate;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getBookName() {
        return bookName;
    }

    public void setBookName(String bookName) {
        this.bookName = bookName;
    }

    public String getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }

    public void setAuthor(String author) {
        this.author = author;
    }

    public Date getPurchaseDate() {
        return purchaseDate;
    }

    public void setPurchaseDate(Date purchaseDate) {
        this.purchaseDate = purchaseDate;
    }

}
```

LmsRepository.java

```
package com.lms.dao;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

import com.lms.models.Book;

public interface LmsRepository extends JpaRepository<Book, Long>{

}
```

LmsService.java:

```
package com.lms.services;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.lms.dao.LmsRepository;
import com.lms.models.Book;

@Service
public class LmsService {

    @Autowired
    private LmsRepository lmsRepository;

    public Collection<Book> findAllBooks() {
        List<Book> books = new ArrayList<Book>();
        for(Book book : lmsRepository.findAll()) {
            books.add(book);
        }
        return books;
    }

    public String addBook(Book book) {
        lmsRepository.saveAndFlush(book);
        return "added added";
    }
}
```

MainRestController.java

```
package com.lms.controllers.rest;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.lms.services.LmsService;
import java.util.Collection;
import com.lms.models.Book;

@RestController
public class MainRestController {

    @Autowired
    private LmsService lmsService;

    @GetMapping(value = "/")
    public String hello() {
        return "Hello World!";
    }

    @GetMapping("/findAllBooks")
    public Collection<Book> getAllBooks() {
        return lmsService.findAllBooks();
    }

    @PostMapping("/postBook")
    public String addNewBook(@RequestBody Book book) {
        lmsService.addBook(book);
        return "Added";
    }
}
```

application.properties:

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix = /WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix = .jsp

spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/lmsdb?useSSL=false

spring.datasource.username = root

spring.datasource.password = root639

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto= update

logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL = debug
```

When I start the main class as spring boot app , I get message:

```
2020-06-05 17:05:24.458  INFO 13300 --- [           main] com.lms.LmsApplication                   : Starting LmsApplication on BLR-FV2ZKC2 with PID 13300 (C:\Users\Jagrati.Agrawal\Documents\workspace-spring-tool-suite-4-4.6.2.RELEASE\LMS\target\classes started by Jagrati.Agrawal in C:\Users\Jagrati.Agrawal\Documents\workspace-spring-tool-suite-4-4.6.2.RELEASE\LMS)
2020-06-05 17:05:24.478  INFO 13300 --- [           main] com.lms.LmsApplication                   : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-06-05 17:05:26.853  INFO 13300 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFERRED mode.
2020-06-05 17:05:27.019  INFO 13300 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 151ms. Found 1 JPA repository interfaces.
2020-06-05 17:05:29.102  INFO 13300 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2020-06-05 17:05:29.118  INFO 13300 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2020-06-05 17:05:29.118  INFO 13300 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.35]
2020-06-05 17:05:30.604  INFO 13300 --- [           main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner     : At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
2020-06-05 17:05:30.612  INFO 13300 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2020-06-05 17:05:30.613  INFO 13300 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 6009 ms
2020-06-05 17:05:31.169  INFO 13300 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2020-06-05 17:05:31.530  INFO 13300 --- [         task-1] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2020-06-05 17:05:32.012  INFO 13300 --- [         task-1] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.15.Final
2020-06-05 17:05:32.621  WARN 13300 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2020-06-05 17:05:32.844  INFO 13300 --- [         task-1] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.0.Final}
2020-06-05 17:05:33.282  INFO 13300 --- [         task-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2020-06-05 17:05:34.121  INFO 13300 --- [         task-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2020-06-05 17:05:34.211  INFO 13300 --- [         task-1] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
2020-06-05 17:05:37.695 DEBUG 13300 --- [         task-1] org.hibernate.SQL                        : create table hibernate_sequence (next_val bigint) type=MyISAM
2020-06-05 17:05:37.776  WARN 13300 --- [         task-1] o.h.t.s.i.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl     : GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL "create table hibernate_sequence (next_val bigint) type=MyISAM" via JDBC Statement

org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "create table hibernate_sequence (next_val bigint) type=MyISAM" via JDBC Statement
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlString(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:559) [hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlStrings(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:504) [hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.createTable(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:277) [hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.performTablesMigration(GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.java:71) [hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.performMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:207) [hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.doMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:114) [hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:184) [hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:73) [hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:314) [hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:468) [hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1249) [hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) [spring-orm-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) [spring-orm-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:391) [spring-orm-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'type=MyISAM' at line 1
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeInternal(StatementImpl.java:764) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:648) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.execute(ProxyStatement.java:95) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.execute(HikariProxyStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    ... 18 common frames omitted

2020-06-05 17:05:37.777 DEBUG 13300 --- [         task-1] org.hibernate.SQL                        : insert into hibernate_sequence values ( 1 )
2020-06-05 17:05:37.913  WARN 13300 --- [         task-1] o.h.t.s.i.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl     : GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL "insert into hibernate_sequence values ( 1 )" via JDBC Statement

org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "insert into hibernate_sequence values ( 1 )" via JDBC Statement
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlString(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:559) [hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applySqlStrings(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:504) [hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.createTable(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:277) [hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.performTablesMigration(GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.java:71) [hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.performMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:207) [hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.doMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:114) [hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:184) [hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:73) [hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:314) [hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:468) [hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1249) [hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) [spring-orm-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) [spring-orm-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:391) [spring-orm-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'lmsdb.hibernate_sequence' doesn't exist
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeInternal(StatementImpl.java:764) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:648) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.execute(ProxyStatement.java:95) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.execute(HikariProxyStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    ... 18 common frames omitted

2020-06-05 17:05:37.915  INFO 13300 --- [         task-1] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2020-06-05 17:05:37.929  INFO 13300 --- [         task-1] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2020-06-05 17:05:38.689  INFO 13300 --- [           main] pertySourcedRequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped URL path [/v2/api-docs] onto method [springfox.documentation.swagger2.web.Swagger2Controller#getDocumentation(String, HttpServletRequest)]
2020-06-05 17:05:39.115  INFO 13300 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.w.s.WelcomePageHandlerMapping    : Adding welcome page template: index
2020-06-05 17:05:39.499  INFO 13300 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2020-06-05 17:05:39.501  INFO 13300 --- [           main] d.s.w.p.DocumentationPluginsBootstrapper : Context refreshed
2020-06-05 17:05:39.568  INFO 13300 --- [           main] d.s.w.p.DocumentationPluginsBootstrapper : Found 1 custom documentation plugin(s)
2020-06-05 17:05:39.661  INFO 13300 --- [           main] s.d.s.w.s.ApiListingReferenceScanner     : Scanning for api listing references
2020-06-05 17:05:40.122  INFO 13300 --- [           main] DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener : Triggering deferred initialization of Spring Data repositories…
2020-06-05 17:05:40.300  INFO 13300 --- [           main] DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener : Spring Data repositories initialized!
2020-06-05 17:05:40.325  INFO 13300 --- [           main] com.lms.LmsApplication                   : Started LmsApplication in 17.027 seconds (JVM running for 21.465)
```

So the app does get started with above error/warning messages and I am able to hit /findAllBooks thru swagger and it works fine, but when I hit /postBook, I get error on swagger "TypeError: Failed to fetch".

Please help.

Comment: The full stacktrace will tell you what is wrong, only posting to lines of the fullstracktrace isn't going to help.

Comment: Could you try by adding `@Repository` on your `LmsRepository `

Comment: @SSK  : still Same error .

Comment: Could you add all your stack trace here? It's hard to identify the error with single line

Comment: @SSK , please check my edits on the question. I have attached the output when I start the app. There seems some warnings/errors..may be that will give insight into what's going wrong.

Comment: `Error executing DDL "insert into hibernate_sequence values ( 1 )" via JDBC Statement`
Due to the above error, your id is not generated. Try using a different strategy with sequence number

Comment: @SSK , I changed dialect from spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect to 
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect and it is working now. I dont get any error when the app starts up..thanks a ton.